# How do i use nested ternary operator in my code? Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to use nested ternary operator in my code

Code:

```
let ele_Partition = records[0].data.meeting ?  
  records[0].data.meeting.partition : records[0].data.partition;
```

Need to add another data for the same condition.

```
records[0].data.meeting.meetingPartition
```

How to implement it without nested if-else?

Comment: Just wrap your inner ternary expression in parentheses and put it in the place of one of your variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "add another data"? How would you want to combine the data?

Comment: What did you try with `if`/`else`, can you please show us that attempt?

Comment: `How to use nested ternary operator` you don't. Not unless you hate developers that will work on the code. Note that this can also be you.

Comment: @JMR I'm sure Bergi knows what if/else condition means. He wants to see it as it'll help him help you by knowing how exactly the ternary needs to look given that your if/else works the way you want it to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS Ternary functions with multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022445/js-ternary-functions-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let ele_Partition = records[0].data.meeting ? 
  records[0].data.meeting.partition : records[0].data.meeting.meetingPartition ? 
    records[0].data.meeting.meetingPartition : records[0].data.partition;
```

If `records[0].data.meeting`, set the variable to `records[0].data.meeting.partition`.

Else if `records[0].data.meeting.meetingPartition`, set the variable to `records[0].data.meeting.meetingPartition`

Else set the variable to `records[0].data.partition`.

You should avoid nested ternary operators as they make your code incredibly complicated to read.

Comment: Nested ternaries are only hard to read when not indenting them properly :-)

Comment: @Bergi The indentation is mine, I hope you are ok with that

Comment: @mplungjan I saw, it's much better than the original :-) I personally prefer [this kind of indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22998100/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a single ternary with a default value

```
let ele_Partition = records[0].data.meeting
        ? records[0].data.meeting.partition
        : records[0].data.meeting.meetingPartition || records[0].data.partition;
```

Comment: Not super clear if that will shortcut on `records[0].data.meeting.meetingPartition || records[0].data.partition;`

Comment: @mplungjan techincally, it should. The ternary would be evaluated to one value of `meeting.partition` or `meeting.meetingPartition` and then the result would be ORed with `data.partition`. Assuming the ternary produces a truthy value, it'd just shortcut. However, whether that's the correct logic or not I can't say - OP hasn't clarified. Also, I agree with the more general sentiment that the expression can be confusing to figure out.